# console.log script returns "Wrong channel!"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm setting up a Discord bot, and I want it to send a message to the main channel of my server when I type `node .`. I typed:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  const Channel = client.channels.cache.get('<My.General.Channel.ID#>');
  if (!Channel) return console.log('Wrong channel!');
  else Channel.send('I am here');
});
```

I get "Wrong channel!". I should just insert the channel ID number, right? I've directly pasted from Discord's "Copy ID" and still get a problem.

**Edit:**

I updated my intents and my code. It now shows:

```
client.on('ready', message => {
  client.channels.cache.get('channel-id').send('message.')
```

This resolved my issues.

Comment: have you tried passing the channel id into the `.get()` call?

Answer (score -1):

if you're using v12 this must be work for your error.

```js
client.on("message", function(message) {
  const Channel = message.channel.id == <My.General.Channel.ID#>;
  if (!Channel) return console.log('Wrong channel!');
  else message.channel.send('I am here');
});
```

Comment: No errors, but no message either.